# Sending API requests from MusicBrowserServiceCompat in Android Auto

Tags: android, android-auto

I am trying to build a music app like Spotify. I am having difficulties in integrating the app with Android Auto. I have a background service extended from `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` that plays music. In Android auto mode, when and from where I send a request to the remote server to get playlists and songs?

I checked the Google's Universal Player codes, I couldn't understand how they are getting the songs (and it was in Kotlin... the codes were too short to understand)
https://github.com/android/uamp

I also found `MediaBrowserCompat` that has something to do with connections, however I am not sure whether it is a API connection or a Service.

How do I do it? How do we send requests to a remote server, get results, and populate them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So just to clarify your question, you are trying to replicate Google's Universal Player codes which can be found https://github.com/android/uamp, but in java and you aren't sure where they are calling the API/getting the songs themselves?

It appears that they are creating a ConnectionService in [AutomotiveMusicService.kt](https://github.com/android/uamp/blob/master/automotive/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/automotive/AutomotiveMusicService.kt) and from that they are calling the API in the [common section](https://github.com/android/uamp/blob/master/common/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/common/MediaSessionConnection.kt).

I think [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/developers/demos/+/7c700e80b902c8f7778ffd63c287ac5710fd69ef/MusicDemo) music demo might also help as I believe it is accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I checked your last link and it is truly a source of knowledge. I have not implemented it yet and I have to say it is little bit of difficult for me to grasp due to my beginner Android mind. But I will choose your answer as the correct one.